# How does one serialize a firefox profile in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

All,

I am trying to setup a firefox profile to run some selenium tests in a docker container selenium standalone firefox.(https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-firefox/) . However, I am not able to integrate the capabilities, profile and options into the remote web driver...

I keep get a type error when i try to include the profile stuff..

```
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type FirefoxProfile is not JSON serializable
```

This is what I have so far...

firefox.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
capabilities['marionette'] = True

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("accept_untrusted_certs", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)
profile.update_preferences()

options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)



driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="http://localhost:4444",
    desired_capabilities=capabilities,
    options=options
)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

search_input_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")

search_input_box.send_keys("selenium webdriver" + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(60)

driver.quit()
```

If I remove the profile, or options settings, it works fine, but I would like to be able to play around wit the settings if I could. Could some one point out what I am missing?

ta,

x

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="http://localhost:4444",
    desired_capabilities=capabilities,
    browser_profile=profile

)
```

instead of calling the options. Looks like the order of params should be command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy according to [this](https://groups.google.com/g/webdriver/c/D5_I4ewgN1U)

Comment: I saw that one, however, I would be getting error "firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object"  warning, so I thought I would try to wrap the profile into the options.... but, it is not serializable for some reason...  ?  But, your reply is good for getting it working. I would not be able to set the options, but maybe I can find something to help with that....

Answer (score 0):

So, the update options are able to be passed like so ...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time, os


timeout = 10
current_dir = os.getcwd()
remote_url = "http://localhost:4444"

options=Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
#options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--width=1080")
options.add_argument("--height=680")
options.set_preference("accept_untrusted_certs", True)
options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream")
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", current_dir)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
options.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
options.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
options.set_preference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional",  "about:blank")
options.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore")
#options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
#options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
#options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
#options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)

#driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=remote_url,
    options=options
)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

search_input_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")

search_input_box.send_keys("selenium webdriver" + Keys.ENTER)

print(driver.page_source)
time.sleep(timeout)

driver.quit()
```